# Grails rest api /curl - limit of 10 records for list

Tags: grails

I am not sure if this is a curl or grails question - I suspect grails.

if I bootstrap a grails 3 rest application with 9 records and run curl to list them, I get 9 records.

10 bootstrap records show 10 records with list curl.

11 bootstrap records show 10 records with listing via curl.

So is there a default value of 10 with the rest api? If so, how can it be changed?

The controller code is auto generated by rest profile so is standard.

```
package heroes2

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        delete "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"delete")
        get "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"index")
        get "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"show", method: "OPTIONS")
        post "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"save")
        put "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"update")
        patch "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"patch")

        "/"(controller: 'application', action:'index')
        "500"(view: '/error')
        "404"(view: '/notFound')
    }
}
```

domain is

```
package heroes2
import grails.rest.*
@Resource(uri = '/heroes', readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Hero {
    String name
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Question #1: what does your controller code look like?

Comment: added UrlMappings.groovy to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your "problem" might the following code (regarding max) in your **scaffolded** index-method in your controller:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond Hero.list(params), model:[heroCount: Hero.count()]
}
```

You can set the **offset** and **max** params in your call like

```
/heroes?offset=10&max=30
```

for instance to get it page-wise

or change the code for the scaffolded controller or create a controller with

```
static scaffold=Hero
```

and only the method heroes with:

```
def heroes() {
    respond Hero.list(params)
}
```